# Android Studio - What tools are available to check for dependency loops or duplicate dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently run into a scenario where I spent a couple hours trying to track down a Gradle issue which reported a TransformException. The error message was unhelpful in tracking down the *actual* issue which was that I had accidentally added dependencies that overlapped (i.e., duplicate dependencies).

### Are there tools available to help me find or fix duplicate dependencies in my Android Studio project?

Is there anything I can do to prevent duplicate dependency issues from happening in the future?

By the way, I only saw this issue in Android Studio 2.0 (which I know is a canary build), but I had never seen the Gradle build process crash because of duplicate dependencies in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can view all your dependencies using the **androidDependencies** or **dependencies** task via gradle.

```
gradlew androidDependencies
```

Your dependencies will be listed in a tree similar to the one below:

```
debug
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
```